# RtpStream mic volume level

Tags: java, android, audio, rtp

We are using android.net.rtp to stream audio between android devices.

However we are getting very inconstant audio levels between devices. Of the three devices we have tested on one is just right, one is very quiet (you can hardly hear it) and the other is so loud it is distorted.

Is there some way to normalize the recorded audio level coming from the Mic before sending it over the RTP Stream?

We can't solve this buy adjusting the playback volume because we would have to change it every time we got a call from a different device.

Below is the code we are using, which works great apart from the large mic audio level differences between devices.

```
AudioManager audioManager.setMode(audioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);

audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

AudioCodec codec = AudioCodec.getCodec(TYPE, RTP_MAP, FMTP);

audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddressLocal);

audioStream.setCodec(codec);
audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);

audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, remotePort);

localPort = String.valueOf(audioStream.getLocalPort());
audioStream.join(audioGroup);
```